# Undefined Procedure in SWI-Prolog does not work

Tags: prolog, undefined, procedure

I am just starting to use Prolog, and already I've run into problem with a seemingly simple example.  Here is my .pl file:

```
hacker(P) :- mountaindew(P), doesntsleep(P).
hacker(P) :- writesgoodcode(P).
writesgoodcode(jeff).
```

Then, after I load the program into swipl, I test it with this line at the prompt

```
writesgoodcode(jeff).
```

I thought it would display true, but I get this error:

```
?- hacker(jeff).
ERROR: hacker/1: Undefined procedure: mountaindew/1
   Exception: (7) hacker(jeff) ?
```

This program works fine, but this doesn't solve my problems:

```
hacker(P) :- writesgoodcode(P).
writesgoodcode(jeff).

$ swipl -s dumb.pl
% dumb.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1,112 bytes

?- hacker(jeff).
true.
```

Can anyone explain why my original program doesn't work?  From my understanding, Prolog should "skip" the first statement since it doesn't have enough information, and check the next line.  It **does** have enough info for that second line, and thus it should evaluate true.  Any help or a point in the right direction would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As the error message says, you have an undefined procedure `mountaindew/1`. To make your code return true, your options are:

1. Define this predicate
2. Declare that this predicate is dynamic: `dynamic(mountaindew/1)`
3. Declare that all unknown predicates should fail (not recommended): `set_prolog_flag(unknown, fail)`

Answer (score 0):

you could also change the order of the predicates (cannot be done always ofc)
but mostly what Kaarel said.

in the end there is not really a point in writing something that will always fail, even if you are still developing the code

Answer (score 0):

This works but as I am a beginner I can't say why. The word "uninstantiated" may apply. Despite not knowing *why* it works, I think it's helpful to show one way that works.

```
hacker(P) :- mountaindew(P), doesntsleep(P).
hacker(P) :- writesgoodcode(P).
mountaindew(john).
doesntsleep(john).
writesgoodcode(jeff).
```